# My homemade vinaigrettes are fermenting and fizzing

Tags: fermentation, salad-dressing, vinaigrette

I make vinaigrette's using dehydrated fruit powders. Been doing it the same way for over a year. Now all are fermenting and fizzing. I mix the powder with agave nectar, wisk my oil and vinegar separately, combine both with water blend and bottle. I have 10 flavors and vinegar varies from red wine, white wine,balsamic and apple cider. I recently tried the hot fill method, still fizz! I'm stumped after doing it one way so long..now I can't seem to get it right. Please advise.

Comment: How are you storing the vinaigrette?

Comment: Also, what are the proportions of the ingredients?

Comment: After it's made I store in boxes in my dining room. For a batch of 12 bottles I use 10 cups water, 1 cip sunflower oil, 1 cup vinegar 1 cup agave nectar for my base, then mix 2 tblspns of fruit powder. My fruity ones are 3 fruit combinations example: raspberry, pomegranate pineapple is one flavor...strawberry blueberry peach is another

Comment: Even vinaigrette without water is normally recommended to be kept in the fridge.  I actually managed to find a recipe that added some water, but far less than yours: [serious eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/simple-vinaigrette-recipe) add 1 tbsp water to 3 tbsp vinegar

Answer (score 6):

The recipe you described will not produce a shelf-stable mixture. The acidity is too low to inhibit the growth of bacteria or mold, and any stray wild yeasts will greedily eat up the agave nectar.

I can't say why this is only now happening. My first guess would be that one of your ingredients previously contained an added preservative, and no longer does so. If that were the case, adding some preservative on your own could help; but preservative dosing takes you out of the realm of Official FDA Recommendations and is thus out-of-scope for this site.

In any case, there's nothing intrinsic to your recipe that would prevent microbe growth. The mystery is not why things are bad now, but why they were okay before.

Comment: Storage temperature, maybe? Before it was winter, now it's summer in the northern hemisphere.

Comment: Maybe so, but that would be more a matter of degree [no pun intended]... presumably these vinaigrettes were being kept for a while.

Comment: I've heated the mixture..bottled it hot and it's still fizzing..

Comment: What can I use for a natural preservative?? I

Comment: "Natural" preservatives, at a high enough level to be effective, will likely change the taste more than you would find acceptable. If it were me, I'd use sodium benzoate.

Comment: Good morning and thank you so much for the info! I did some research and was going to ask you about using this and you already answered my question! should I add it using my old method of mixing powders and liquid, or should I do the hot fill method?

Comment: Also..does potassium sorbate serve the same purpose?

Comment: Hot fill  is probably going to help some, so I’d stick with that. Do *not* measure your benzoate by volume [the stuff is ineffective or dangerous at the wrong concentration]; get a precision scale. I suspect that sodium/potassium are interchangeable (they are with other preservatives) but I don’t have much experience there. You might want to post a new question about that.

Comment: Or guar gum? The sodium benzoate will add sodium, don't really wanna do that

Comment: Guar gum is a thickener, not a preservative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137758/discussion-between-samantha-hines-and-sneftel).

Comment: If you want a "natural" preservative, why not just use a proper quantity of vinegar (especially as you're considering citric acid, from chat)

Answer (score 1):

Are you keeping these at room temperature? You should be fine if you keep them in the fridge. That being said, Fermentation is a result of temperature (warm ferments faster), sugar (which you're adding), cultures (which you might be adding via apple cider, wine, or fruit), water (which you have a lot of) and time. If you don't want to mess around with your ingredient ratios to make it more acidic or less sugary you can also do smaller batches so you use it before it ferments.

Comment: Large batches save time. I sell at 3 farmers markets and work a full time job I don't have time to do small batches, was considering adding potassium sorbate,  what are your thouggts?