# Best natural preservative for vinaigrettes

Tags: salad-dressing

I make organic and all Natural Vinaigrette's,  lately they're fermenting and fizzing. Whats the best preservative to use? Guar gum, potassium sorbate? Don't want added sodium from sodium benzoate.

Comment: The vinegar, oil, and salt that are part of a vinaigrette are preservative already, so that seems a bit strange to me. After how much time are your vinaigrettes fermenting/fizzing? A day, a week, a month?

Comment: @JohnDoe see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121031/my-homemade-vinaigrettes-are-fermenting-and-fizzing . The vinegar is diluted 10:1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My homemade vinaigrettes are fermenting and fizzing](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121031/my-homemade-vinaigrettes-are-fermenting-and-fizzing)

Comment: The main preservative in vinaigrette is vinegar.  This isn't vinaigrette.  Not with 10:1 water.

Comment: Why is asking about preservatives off-topic?

Comment: @GdD I don't think it is.  The close vote is mine as a duplicate of the OP's previous question - not that the question is the same but that the answer pretty much would be

Comment: That question was asking why the fizzing was happening, not about how to stop it. It seems a logical follow-up question to me.

Comment: Hey folks, this is not a duplicate, it is a follow-up question, something we encourage people to ask rather than putting multiple questions in one topic.

Comment: Esther: there is no precedent that questions about preservatives are off-topic.

Comment: Samantha: this question should include your rough recipe, since what you're making is not a normal vinagrette.

Comment: Close vote retracted - I realised it was *my* answer that would be practically the same, not all decent answers.

Answer (score 3):

The best preservative for salad dressing is [high acid content](https://extension.sdstate.edu/making-safe-salad-dressing); below pH 4.5, most pathogens will not reproduce.  However, most salad dressings are above that, and yours certainly is due to the large quantity of water you add.

The next method used [is heat](https://extension.sdstate.edu/making-safe-salad-dressing); this is how commercial salad dressings are made shelf-stable.  I have a bottle of Ken's Caesar in my pantry right now that containts zero preservatives, and is shelf-stable for months or years, through heat treatment.  For that to be effective, you must follow safe canning practices and heat filled bottles to at least the temperatures and times listed in the linked article.  In fact, you may need higher temperatures and longer times, or even pressure canning, due to the very low acidity of your dressing.

There are chemical preservatives that you can add, but none of them protect your customers from all pathogens.  For example, sodium benzoate is often used to [prevent yeast and mold](https://foodsafety.wisc.edu/assets/pdf_Files/GMP_sauces_NebEntre.pdf), but does nothing to inhibit botulism or salmonella.

Comment: That first link uses a strange definition of "salad dressing", quoting the FDA: they say egg is a required ingredient, implying mayonnaise and things made from it.  The arguments on pH  should still hold though

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but it's still a fairly authoritative source.

Comment: The FDA is authoritative, but if they're talking about something completely different, they're not useful. I'm not sure whether they're being slightly inappropriately quoted in your source, or if there's an FDA definition of salad dressing that excludes vinaigrette

Comment: Vinagrettes (without eggs) are "non-standardized food dressings" in the FDA category system, as mentioned in the article.  But SDSU's recommendations on acidification still apply.  Particularly for the OP's question, where one of the chief problems is that their dressing is very low-acid (neutral).

Comment: I agree about the acidity - and my nitpicking about FDA terminology didn't stop me voting for your answer - but I didn't want to let the strange definition go unnoticed. I'm not sure what this dressing should be called, but it's not vinaigrette - if it was, there probably wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the FDA (or ESFA) doesn't have specific guidance for "rehydrated fruit juice with vinegar and spices".

Answer (score -1):

**Canning.**

You like your microbes because you are making vinagrette (I think).  But lately they are too frisky with the bubbling and fizzing and you want them to quit it.

You can kill them with heat.  You can can them.  Or you *may* can them.  Once they are at the point you like as regards fixx and flavor open the bottles (no heating closed bottles, ever!) and have them sit in the hot water bath just as you would for canning.  Canning works by killing microbes.  The same procedure will kill the microbes responsible for the fizzing you don't want.

Canning can change flavors but probably not as much as adding enough salt or other substance to chemically suppress the microbes.  Once your vinaigrette product is sterilized it should be fizz free.